# WebDav - Forbidden on Browsers

Tags: google-chrome, webdav

I'm trying to create a server using a raspberry pi but before that i decided to test it first in a virtual machine. So, I created two folders webdav and webdav2 inside /var/www/ and they worked nicely (Chrome and nautilus shows its contents and I also could add files to it). However, when i tried to create a server in /mnt/webdav_share I didn't have the same success. I can access it on Nautilus but in Chrome I get "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource.

Here's my config file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav
    <Location /webdav>
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/webdav/passwd.dav
    Require valid-user
    </Location>

    Alias /webdav2 /var/www/webdav2
    <Location /webdav2>
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav2"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/webdav2/.secrets/passwd.dav
    Require valid-user
    </Location>

    Alias /webdav_share /mnt/webdav_share
    <Directory /mnt/webdav_share>
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav_share"
    AuthUserFile /mnt/webdav_share/.secrets/passwd.dav
    Require valid-user
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The files properties

```
    drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  4 21:50 webdav_share
    drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  4 20:11  .secrets
    -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   44 Apr  4 20:32 passwd.dav
```

Thanks,

Eduardo

Comment: Are you perhaps using the snap version of chrome? if so... it will be sandboxed.

Comment: I do, but this also happens with other browsers

Comment: Just for the sake of the of testing I moved the folder from /mnt/ to /var/www/, Directory to Location and reloaded apache. It worked. So, what would be making it not to work in the other folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is here:

> By default, Ubuntu does not allow access through the web browser to
> any file apart of those located in /var/www, public_html directories
> (when enabled) and /usr/share (for web applications). If your site is
> using a web document root located elsewhere (such as in /srv) you may
> need to whitelist your document root directory in
> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.
>
> The default Ubuntu document root is /var/www/html. You can make your
> own virtual hosts under /var/www. This is different to previous
> releases which provides better security out of the box.

Just added my folder to the file and it started working

Thanks